# Adding Parameters to ServiceStack's base path

Tags: routes, servicestack

Is there a way to add a route parameter to the base factory path in ServiceStack?
Currently, we configure IIS to route any requests starting with `/api/` to the `ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory` through the *web.config*.

```
<location path="api">
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>

  <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

In addition, we tell the ServiceStack application that it has a base factory path of `api` through the endpoint host config in *AppHost.cs*

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api" });
```

Once this is done, we specify the routes to our services through the `[Route]` attribute on our request DTOs, and we don't have to worry about the '/api' part.

Is there a way to add a global parameter to the path's route? The idea would be to add this parameter in the config `/api/{Locale}` and then all of our request DTOs would inherit from a `BaseRequest` class with a property `string Locale {get;set;}`.

As an added bonus, if it was possible to make this an optional parameter (likely through two routes in `web.config` & `AppHost.cs`) to allow for a 'default' value of this parameter that'd be even better.

---

**EDIT**

I'm currently exploring the idea of creating a class extending the `RouteAttribute` class.

```
public class PrefixedRouteAttribute : RouteAttribute
{
  public static string Prefix = string.Empty;
  public PrefixedRouteAttribute(string path) : base(Prefix + path)
  public PrefixedRouteAttribute(string path, string verbs) : base(Prefix + path, verbs)
}
```

The Prefix value can be set in `AppHost.cs` to `/{Locale}`, which will automatically inject the Locale parameter into all routes, provided I use `[PrefixedRoute]` instead of `[Route]`.

This approach seems to be working, except I don't see a way to make the `{Locale}` optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
public abstract class BaseDto
{
    public string Locale { get; set; }

    public BaseDto()
    {
        Locale = "en";
    }
}

[Route("/{Locale*}/test")]
public class TestDto : BaseDto
{
    public int SomeParam { get; set; }
}

public class TestService : Service
{
    public Result Get(TestDto request)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Responding Amir. I'm no longer working on that project, so I can't verify your response. However, since you're the only one who gave any answer at all, and conceivably this looks like it should work, I'll mark this as correct.